# Google App Engine - required=True clarification

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

in my Google App Engine app, is there any extra overhead in terms of speed/cost to adding required=True to my model entity properties?

I was thinking of not adding required=True to any of my entity properties and just use my application code to safeguard against null values in an effort to have the cheapest possible app that scales the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Property Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options):

> required  bool    False   Property must have a value specified.

There is a tiny extra delay the first time when you call a `.put()` on that entity, since that property has to be set, so a slightly bigger amount of data will be passed through RPC.

I wouldn't call that a scalability issue though - subsequent such `.put()` call no longer have that requirement since the property is already set (assuming it wasn't deleted in the meantime).

And there is not cost implications - the number of `.put()` calls is not affected.